# what is the 100% of a color? The 30% hex value is provided

Tags: color, transparency

basically i want to know about the 100% of a color.
The 30% hex of the color is #00bcd4.
My developer wants to know the 100% of the color.

Yes i also told her the same.. that #color code itself is a 100% color. The developer is designing some custom switch for that she told me that 30% of a color is #00bcd4. The 100% of the color #00bcd4 is what? :( I explained that i can lower the opacity of color #00bcd4 to 30% and then will let you know the value (keeping white as a base). But she said no.. that is not the question.. how do i explain it to developer?

Comment: There is no such thing as a '30% hex'. A hex code is a full color code, no opacity included. I'm not sure what you or your developer is asking, you might want to give us some more context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to revert preapplied alpha blend and find original color?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/is-it-possible-to-revert-preapplied-alpha-blend-and-find-original-color). You need to know the background color to be able to deduce the answer

Comment: the developer is surely asking about some detail of a design specification or template.  Did you provide a layout or image that the developer is trying to replicate in code?

Answer (score 1):

What we have here is failure in communication.

> she told me that 30% of a color is #00bcd4

So if we assume that she provided you with that hex number the question is how she arrived at it? She should have 100% called X because she know what 30% of X is.

So what you should ask is "So what is the question"? Who said that #00bcd4 is 30%?
There are too many values that could be lowered to 30% to have this result. Hue, Saturation, Opacity, all channels at once or just one channel. 
There are too many variables and too little information.

Answer (score 0):

If the colour you have would be a pastel or light colour, you'd be able to convert it into the HSB colour model by introducing it into a colour picker like Adobe's. There, you could increase the saturation to intensify the colour, as if it became more opaque on a white background.

Unfortunately, the colour you give is already fully saturated and should thus be a '100% colour'.

[image: Colour picker with #00bcd4 in HSB mode]

Answer (score 0):

OK let's do some maths...

So, we can assume than the color you are looking for has been tinted with 70% white and result is #00BCD4. Right?

Hex #00BCD4 converted to RGB is R0, G188, B212

```
R = 000 = Rx + (255 - Rx) * 0.7  
G = 188 = Gx + (255 - Gx) * 0.7  
B = 212 = Bx + (255 - Bx) * 0.7
```

Rx, Gx and Bx are the values you are looking for, for each channel.

OK let's go, here are rounded values:
Rx = **-595 !! Ooopps**
Gx = 32
Bx = 112

So can now prove mathematically to your developer than this is just not possible. Your color (#00BCD4) is way too saturated to be a 30% tint of a color.
If he don't want to hear it, ask him what is the 100% reference of #000000 which is supposed to be a 30% tint. I'd be curious to hear his answer. ^^

Comment: Well kindof but the question does not specify the background color. This can work out for some colors. But not back and white. But for this to work out one thing is certain R has to be 0. Also your formula has a mistake the other value needs to be bg color. But yes i find it pretty unlikely thet the BG is such a weird color.

Comment: @joojaa The OP did not write it was a 30% transparency with a non-white background. So I just assumed we were talking about tint, or 30% alpha over a white background. Maybe I assumed wrongly, but I hope that the OP would have specified a colored background if there was any... Btw, where is the mistake in the formula?

Comment: Writing the formula in vector form (to avoid repeating myself) is `FG*opacity + BG *(1 - opacity)`. Expanding this in your form vectorized  this is: `FG*0.7 + 255*0.3=x` manipulating it more you get ´FG = (x-255*0.3)/0.7`

Comment: Hmm,  I'm not a math specialist like you seem to be, but shouldn't it be FG = (x-255*0.7)/0.3 ? If I get it right, your formula applies to a 70% tint, not 30%... Anyway, I think we all agree the #00bcd4 color CAN'T be a 30% tint of a color, which basically was the original question^^

Comment: its just the inverse, but no its not possible on white... But can be possible on some blue

Comment: This is all predicated on the idea that the developer is asking for a 30% tint of anything . He/she is not. The question is clearly that the developer needs to know what the color used for the tint is, since presumably the developer is going to use that actual color to use in a dynamically generated blend.

Comment: @Yorik yes that is what im talking about. But it seems odd that the designer would be in this situation. But as i said we cant know the tint since we dont know what color the tint is on. White is not possible for those values.