# Find color where alpha at value `a` equals a given hue

Tags: color, color-theory, color-conversion, color-reproduction

I want to achieve a certain hue but also have the color that carries that hue contain a certain opacity.

For example if I were after `#ff0000` with `50%` opacity, the color I would want to identify is the (dark) shade of red that when at `50%` opacity yields `#ff0000`.

Is there an equation I can use that lets me plug in the desired hue and alpha to identify the color values that produce that hue when at the given opacity value?

(I know this won't exist for all target color / alpha combinations, but I'd like to find the equation that specifies the parameters for those combinations that are achievable.)

Comment: That entirely depends on what the background color is. But it seems rather unikely that youd get #FF0000 with any intelligent pair with alpha blending. Anyway you should read: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/is-it-possible-to-revert-preapplied-alpha-blend-and-find-original-color/78250#78250

Comment: @joojaa awesome work! I feel I should just go ahead and close this now, though those other questions didn't come up when I was Googling. Should I close this or do you want to link to your answer for further Google juice? Also do you have a website / blog? I'd like to read more of your work!

Comment: Well your wording was a bit confused as to what it is it isyou were asking. But in general i feel hesitant to close with a unaccepted answer