# Add transparency without lightening the color

Tags: color, android, blending

I'm certain there's a more accurate term for what I'm seeking, but I'm unsure of what it might be. So...

I basically need to do this:
[image]

The image features a solid black background. On this background there are two squares side by side. The square on the left is colored #555555. The square on the right is colored #5E5E5E, but it has 90% opacity revealing a bit of a red circle beneath it. I adjusted the right square's color values manually to achieve the desired effect: it should appear identical to the left square when placed on the black background, yet with a 10% transparency to subtly show what's underneath.

When using a black background, the task was straightforward. However, I'm aiming to create a function that takes in three parameters: the background color (e.g., black), the foreground color (e.g., #555555), and the opacity (e.g., 10%). This function should then return a color (e.g., #5E5E5E) that, when the specified opacity is applied, will match the original foreground color on the given background.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159945/is-there-a-program-or-tool-that-can-determine-the-alpha-value-of-a-color-given-i/159959#159959 ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Might not be as simple as you expect. There will be color combinations where no solutions exists. For example if the gray square in your example was white. Just adding a tiny bit of transparency will make the white darker. Or a red square on a blue background etc.

Comment: @joojaa I tried that, thanks. But it returns a color which is close enough, but still different.... I think that will be acceptable, will need to test. Thanks

Comment: @Wolff it's to use as an effect for some UI elements in an app. That example you gave would be fine as it may never happen because all colors involved are some sort of gray shading.

Comment: So are you aiming at programming your own custom blend mode of sorts? Or just manually select color and transparency for each object? If it's the latter you could just start with the transparent boxes and measure the resulting colors on a screenshot?

Comment: I would like to program it... That would be ideal.