# How do I calculate color gradients?

Tags: gradient

I have a small table of values like this:

```
Food     Count   Color
Pumpkin  345     #DB3236
Cabbage  193     ?
Pepper   89      ?
Beetroot 96      ?
Potato   62      ?
Lettuce  35      ?
Carrot   26      ?
Tomato   25      ?
Banana   22      ?
Apple    22      #FADBDB
```

I want to calculate a color gradient between #DB3236 and #FADBDB based on the COUNT values.

For example "Pumpkin" = 345 and has the strongest color, and "Apple" = 22 which is the weakest color. Even though "Potato" is in the middle of my table it only has a Count value of 62 which means it will be quite weak on the color gradient scale.

I'm not great with numbers so I'm really struggling how to figure this out.

How do I create the color gradient for the other foods on my table?

Comment: Colors are not linear so doing this calculation even for a very mathematcally talented is hard since as a definition it makes little sense. But if you want it to act linear then draw ticks by distance next to a gradient.

Comment: Could you expand further upon the idea of ticks by distance? I don't understand the concept. There is a site here that calculates the gradient steps between two colors http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/ but the highest amount is 64 steps and I need more than that for my data table.

Comment: This site calculates up to 255 steps: http://www.herethere.net/~samson/php/color_gradient/ it the most I can find, but still not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered this JavaScript fiddle which works great!

You input two RGB colors and choose how many color steps you want to output. It will then give you a list of colors along your given gradient: https://jsfiddle.net/002v98LL/

Copy the list of colors into Excel to figure out which color corresponds to which gradient step.

And you can use Google or some other tool if you need to convert between Hex and RGB codes.

Answer (score 5):

As commented color is not linear, nor countable, so from a strictly physical point of view it makes little sense to do this. However you can approximate color as being linear for your purpose. While this is potentially misleading you can do it, human senses aren't that precise when it comes to absolute color variation so no worries. This should explain why is may be a bad idea for example for infographics

Anyway there is a simple visual relationship in your data and what you want to do. Just plot the points next to a gradient in y direction with values in y.

[image]

Note that you have very little color variation at the bottom. If instead of showing spatial relationship i would only show swatches you wouldn't have much of anything to show for it. So I suggest more different colors in your gradient (which necessitates showing the scale).

Anyway linear is easy to calculate:

```
color = x * start_color + (x-1) * end_color
```

where x is (count-min)/(max-min)

```
#DB3236 is 219 50 54 in decimals and 
#FADBDB 250 219 219 in decimals
```

So for color the interpolant is simply

```
red =   (count-22)/323 * 219 + ( 1 - (count-22)/323 ) * 250
green = (count-22)/323 *  50 + ( 1 -  (count-22)/323 ) * 219
blue =  (count-22)/323 *  54 + ( 1 - (count-22)/323 ) * 219
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a color picker to grab the colors I needed from your example image. Although I have the same problem again for a different set of data, so I'm trying to figure out how to recreate this again for myself but I can't understand how the code works. The last part (red, green, red, etc) is especially confusing for me. Was your code executed in Python or something similar? Mind sharing the script?

Comment: @bennygill its mathematics. What language do you use?

Comment: I am learning Python right now if you have a script for that it would be amazing! Maths is not my strong point haha.

Comment: You can find a simnilar code [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/faded-colour-code-calculation/46870#46870). But i can edit one example in later @bennygill

Comment: I tried that example but I can't get it to work. And I've been playing around with lots of other code but still no luck. I'm a novice coder, so any examples you can give for this would be great please.

Comment: @bennygill most python code out there is for python 2.x so you need to port most code. Some versions of python 3 line do not ship witg tinkter

Comment: Try canging the import line to start with a lower case t

Comment: I got it working but it outputs an image that isn't very useful for me because it doesn't tell me which step corresponds to which color, also it's really large and I can't scroll down in the TK window to see the whole pic. See here: https://snag.gy/S3wmaA.jpg. How did you export the picture and know which part corresponded to which gradient step?